# Understanding Fabric Z-Index

Tags: javascript, z-index, fabricjs

I'm having a hard time understanding the moveto function of an canvas objet.
I´m trying to load object and position them, according to my z-index plan.
This may result in an object loaded earlier then another object, but with a higher Z-Index the the later loaded.
But this is not working as planed. Is Fabric just adding one on the other, according to their time-wise addition to the canvas?

Here is the code for setting the Z-Index.

```
function makeMySvg(urlNames,yvalues,xvalues,zvalues,dasArray,theCanvas)
{
    var targetUrl = urlNames.shift();
    var targetY = yvalues.shift();
    var targetX = xvalues.shift();
    var targetZ = zvalues.shift();
    if (targetUrl){
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(targetUrl,

    function(objects)
    {

            var obj = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, {
              //left: versatzx-14, // 1/2 breite 28px hoehe 33px
              //top: versatzy+axpos1/10*factor,
              top: targetY,
              left: targetX,
              opacity: 1,
              scaleX: 1,
              scaleY: 1,
              selectable: true,
              objectCaching: true
            });

            theCanvas.add(obj);
            dasArray.push(obj);
            theCanvas.moveTo(obj, targetZ);
            console.log(targetZ);
            //obj.moveTo(targetZ);
            makeMySvg(urlNames,yvalues,xvalues,zvalues,dasArray,theCanvas);

    });
  }
  theCanvas.renderAll();
}



 var axleUrls =['images/axe180a.svg', 'images/axe180b.svg'];
 var axleY = [versatzy+axpos1/10*factor,versatzy+oldlength*5-axpos2/10*factor-30];
 var axleX = [versatzx-45,versatzx-45];
 var axleZ = [28,29];
 var axle=[];

        makeMySvg(axleUrls, axleY, axleX, axleZ, axle, canvas);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes fabricJS is going to add one on top of the other, depending on the order they finish loading.
You can fix this by adding all the objects in an array instead of doing canvas.add

Start with an array of the same size of the one with the url to load.

```
var myUrls = ['urlA', 'urlB', 'urlC'];
var placeHolders = [null, null, null];

myUrls.forEach(function(url, index) {
  fabric.loadSVGFromURL(targetUrl, function(objects) {
        var obj = new fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, {
          //left: versatzx-14, // 1/2 breite 28px hoehe 33px
          //top: versatzy+axpos1/10*factor,
          top: targetY,
          left: targetX,
          opacity: 1,
          scaleX: 1,
          scaleY: 1,
          selectable: true,
          objectCaching: true
        });
        dasArray.push(obj);
        placeHolders[index] = obj;
  })
});
canvas.add(...placeHolders);
```

Comment: Hello Andrea, thanx for your answer.